# PHP - incorrect colors when using imagecopy

Tags: php, gd

I have couple of png images that were generate like so:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng($full_path_to_file);
imagealphablending($img , true); // setting alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($img , true); // save alphablending setting
```

The images come out fine, with right colors and transparent background.

I need to combine these images into one. For that I do the following:

1. Create an blank image with right dimensions

   `$full_image = imagecreate($full_width, $full_height);`
2. Copy png images one by one onto the blank image

   `imagecopy($full_image, $src, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $src_width, $src_height`)

The images are combined ok. Background is transparent, however *the colors are not correct.*

How can I make sure to get the right colors?

**update:** as suggested, fix is to use `imagecreatetruecolor` Also, I need to set the second parameter to `imagealphablending` to false. So when creating png images and creating a full_image, I call

```
imagealphablending($img , false); // updated to FALSE
imagesavealpha($img , true);
```

Documentation for [imagesavealpha says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php):

> You have to unset alphablending (imagealphablending($im, false)), to
> use it.

Comment: Can you show us what you mean by "not correct"?

Comment: You use you dont have a CMYK file? You wouldn't be the first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using: [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) instead of imagecreate.

Comment: tried it. didn't do anything.  imagecreatetruecolor is for jpegs

Comment: Did you try imagecopymerge the two pngs onto the created imagecreatetruecolor and output that with imagepng?

Comment: one second. i actually tried `imagecreatetruecolor`  again, this time it gives me right colors but background is black instead of transparent

Comment: use the image alpha on the image created by imagecreatetruecolor. That should do the trick.

Comment: Needed to set alpha blending to false. Updated answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

only need to add below code after imagecopy() method called

$white = imagecolorallocate($destination_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($destination_image,0,0,$white);